# dynamically add "data-" attributes to html.listboxfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have the following razor code:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.selectedServices, new MultiSelectList(Model.companyServices, "serviceId", "name"))
```

in the `companyServices`, I have a duration property that I would like to export out on each of the options of the listbox like the following:

```
<select id="selectedServices" name="selectedServices" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="0" data-duration="90">option 1</option>
    <option value="1" data-duration="15">option 2</option>
    <option value="2" data-duration="60">option 3</option>
</select>
```

is there anyway to cleanly and easily do this using the `@Html.ListBoxFor` or do I have to manually create the select using foreach and stuff?

Comment: Without rolling your own HTML helper method you can't do this.

Comment: Oh, one other thought: if you're going to need to reuse this select list across your application you might want to create an editor template for your `companyServices` object.  You could write the `foreach` code within that template and reuse it across your application.

Comment: @Ek0nomik That's what I thought but wasn't sure. the editor template is a great idea :) thanks